# Capistrano 3 RVM not working Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on production.dev , cap aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rvm, capistrano3

I cannot get Capistrano 3 to work with RVM. Tried several ways to fix to no avail.
Suspect a config issue since im using gem set but cannot pinpoint exactly what is wrong.

The output is like:

```
cap production deploy:update_code --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
DEBUG [0aa77269] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on production.com
DEBUG [0aa77269] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
Cap aborted!
```

My Capfile looks like:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

#require 'capistrano/puma'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: Which type of RVM you using system wide or user specific?

Answer (score 1):

try https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3 - it should work just fine